# How to include header in ajax request?

Tags: ajax, header

I need to include a header with a refresh token in an ajax call to the YouTube api. I am trying to send a delete request, to delete a movie I have on my account. This is my ajax call that fire on button click

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        // must set api key
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+ thisUniqueID + '&key=904907387177-qe517sq5dmmpebckjbmrhv4gvac9e2d1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        success: function() {
        alert('your video has been deleted');
        },
        error: function() {
        alert('error processing your requst');
        }
    });
```

I am receiving a 401 (unauthorized) erorr on return and it seems that I need to include my access token in the call. I was playing around with the google api playground looking at the request and response and this is what shows as the 'Request' being sent out

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=3242343&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer "access token"
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

Now from that request it looks like the there are headers that are being sent with the request, which hold the access token. This must be why I am getting a 401 error. How can I include those headers into my ajax request, so that my access token is passed along with the request? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to pass along a header using this code below:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        // must set api key
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+ thisUniqueID +'&key=api_key_here',
beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer access_token_here');},
        success: function() {
        alert('your video has been deleted');
        },
        error: function() {
        alert('error processing your request');
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the difference between using the beforeSend function to contain the header and adding "headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer access_token_here' 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}" into the ajax call?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `beforeSend` method and `request.setRequestHeader`. Take a look at the official documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

P.S. should I post it as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try add the paramenter data.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: 'key=' + {YOUR_API_KEY},
    // must set api key
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+ thisUniqueID + '&key=904907387177-qe517sq5dmmpebckjbmrhv4gvac9e2d1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    success: function() {
    alert('your video has been deleted');
    },
    error: function() {
    alert('error processing your requst');
    }
});
```