# The Request.IsAuthenticated is false when receive an ajax request in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I have a ASP.Net MVC5 application and it have running for several months. However, I have found some strange things today.

If I logged into this application and lay aside one page for an hour without any operation, and then I send an ajax request using JQuery to the server, on the server side, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` is `false`.

However, if  I send a "get" request not ajax request(e.g. just press F5 to refresh this page), the `IsAuthenticated` is `true`. I have check that the `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` cookie is sent to the server correctly.

Why is the `Request.IsAuthenticated` false when receiving an ajax request?

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258721/authorize-attribute-and-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Please show the code that you're using to send the ajax request.  It sounds like the cookies aren't being sent with the ajax request, but are when the browser does a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include an `Authorization` header with the bearer token in the ajax call. Please see this [reponse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746139/2054754) as an example, and don't forget the string `'Bearer '` before the token.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

I have found that I have misunderstood the Get request.In Fact, the Get request is expired too. Since I have SSO server, the browser just redirect to the SSO site and redirect back. That cause I thought the Get requst is not expired.
I have set ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHourss(8) in app.UseCookieAuthentication and then this problem was fixed.